# KeyDown event with user input validation

Tags: c#, winforms

in the following code, I am trying to get only decimal value. but the textfield input comes as different strings. Need to validate against numbers and backspace,delete key

```
if ((e.KeyValue >= 48 && e.KeyValue <= 57) || (e.KeyCode >= Keys.NumPad0 && e.KeyCode <= Keys.NumPad9) && (textBox1.Text.Length < textBox1.MaxLength))
{
    if (e.KeyCode != Keys.Delete && e.KeyCode != Keys.Back)
    {
        if (e.KeyValue >= 48 && e.KeyValue <= 57)
        {
            enteredNumber = e.KeyData.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            enteredNumber = e.KeyData.ToString().Substring(0, 1);
        }
    }
    textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + enteredNumber;
}
```

if i enter 1 in the text box , iam getting its ascii value 149 in the text box since its appending 49 - ascii value of 1 in the text box.Can you suggest how to fix this?

Comment: Why don't you use e.KeyChar?

Comment: What is the result you are expecting?

Comment: after two digits entered, need to updated with decimal separator . KeyChar is not available.

Comment: Would you like to try changing it to KeyPress event?

Answer (score 3):

Please state your problem *clear*. Supposing, that you want to *restrict* user's input
in order to let user input *digits only* ('0'..'9') you can do something like that:

```
  private void myTextbox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e) {
    if (Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar))
      return;
    else if (e.KeyChar < ' ') // <- I suggest that you allow user to press ESC, TAB etc.
      return;

    // Other keys are forbidden
    e.Handled = true;
  }
```

P.S. Remember, however, that user can **paste** something incorrect, in order to prevent that you can use `TextChanged` event:

```
private void myTextbox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (!Regex.IsMatch(myTextbox.Text, @"^\d*$")) {
    // User's trying to PASTE something wrong from the Clipboard
    // Let's, for instance, remove his/her input in that case:
    myTextbox.Text = "";
  }
}
```

Comment: Need to check for numbers and delete, backspace key.

Comment: @rajalakshmi: that's done in "else if (e.KeyChar < ' ')" line, e.g. BackSpace is as far as I remember 8, when ' ' (space) is 32; 'delete' doesn't generate KeyPress event at all